# difference between mime types and extension filtering on IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I got error 404 for a file extension. I did allow it in extension filter it didn't solve, whereas in mime type it's then ok. So what's the purpose of adding a file extension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MIME Type is not defined IIS will return 404.3 code. Apparently **this behaviour is by design.**

> In a nutshell a mime type is a setting
>   which IIS uses to determine how a
>   particular file type is managed. For
>   instance IIS will have a mime type set
>   for the .html extension which will
>   instruct the client web browser to
>   treat the file as text, while the mime
>   type for an .mpg file is configured as
>   a video file which will require an
>   external application outside the web
>   browser. Windows file associations
>   work in a very similar way. Boiled
>   down it simply is a method that is
>   used so that IIS is able to instruct
>   the client on how to deal with files
>   that are being delivered.

"Extension filtering" (Request Filtering -> File Name Extensions) became part of IIS as of v7. For IIS v7.0 you had to download [Administration Pack](http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack) to have it.

Request Filtering is a built-in *security* feature that replaces much of the functionality that was available through the UrlScan add-on for IIS 6.0. When Request Filtering blocks an HTTP request, IIS 7 will return an HTTP 404 error to the client and log the HTTP status with a unique substatus that identifies the reason that the request was denied. 404.7 = File Extension Denied.

With help of Request Filtering you can configure your website/application to not to serve files with specific extensions which otherwise would be available to download. Just an example (not the best, but): lets assume that any *.inc file will be served as plain text, but one of your websites uses this extension for a different purposes (to store some configuration details, for example). This can be easily achieved with the help of Request Filtering.

You can also configure it other way around -- to deny all extensions (for static files only) except those that are explicitly allowed.